# Why if you don't specify --backup-dir, the --omit-dir-times option will be implied?

Tags: rsync

From the manpage of rsync

> **-b, --backup**
>
> With this option, preexisting destination files are renamed as each
>   file is transferred or deleted. You can control where the backup file
>   goes and what (if any) suffix gets appended using the --backup- dir
>   and --suffix options.
>
> Note that **if you don't specify --backup-dir, (1) the --omit-dir-times
>   option will be forced on**

What is the reason that

> if you don't specify --backup-dir, (1) the --omit-dir-times option will be forced on

Comment: Is there a technical problem you are trying to resolve? Your text is taken directly from the man documentation for rsync. This is the way the application behaves. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to ask the development team WHY a function behaves a certain way?

Answer (score 1):

From [the mailing list](https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2017-October/031353.html):

> The backup operations occurring inside the transfer directories cause
>   the directory times to get tweaked, so rsync doesn't support trying to
>   keep those times the same (without moving your backup files
>   elsewhere).
>
> -- Wayne Davison wayned at samba.org
>   Sun Oct 8 15:53:41 UTC 2017